# What is a word for a long period of hibernation before growth?

Tags: single-word-requests, plant-physiology

I am looking for a word or phrase that would describe something as existing but waiting for a catalyst. Or growing very slowly until a a large growth spurt. I'm thinking of the way that seeds can sit healthy until they get wet and planted and then grow quickly.

Comment: Chrysalid, the adjective form of chrysalis is potentially useful

Answer (score 11):

> [***dormant***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dormant):
>    1:  marked by a suspension of activity: as
>    2:  temporarily devoid of external activity 
>    3:  temporarily in abeyance yet capable of being activated

The seeds remain *dormant*, waiting for spring.

Comment: What do you think a good word would be for the growth afterwards?

Comment: [germination](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/germination) - The process of germinating; the beginning of vegetation or growth from a seed or spore.

Comment: Or _dormancy,_ for the noun form.

Answer (score 2):

How about suspended animation?

Answer (score 2):

**[latent](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/latent)**

> (Biology) Undeveloped but capable of normal growth under the proper conditions: a latent bud.

Answer (score 1):

[***quiescence***](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quiescence)

> quiescence: seed dormancy, a form of delayed seed germination

Answer (score 0):

[*stagnant*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stagnant)

> 3.
>
> a. Showing little or no sign of activity or advancement; not developing or progressing; inactive: a stagnant economy.
>   b. Lacking vitality or briskness; sluggish or dull: a stagnant mind.